# Gather unique values from 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have  2 "set" lists, both contain mostly the same values i.e:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

What I'm trying to do is compare the two and only return 7 & 8 into another list however I'm having no luck, I've tried a few methods I've found on here such as:

```
c = [item for item in a if item not in b]
```

However I've had no luck does anyone know a quick and fairly easy method of doing this? Both lists have been "set" previously to remove any duplicates within their own lists also (just felt I should add that if that makes a difference)

Just to be clear, as I think I wasn't sorry, the example values are already in set format, in my head for some reason when you used set on a list it acted like the array_unique PHP function.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you converted them from sets to lists?

Comment: @Adrocks__, are you trying to find unique values from list b or from both lists?

Comment: @ayhan - sorry if it wasn't clear, They started as lists at this current stage they are in sets (for the duplication removal) thats what I tried to mean by "set" lists. 
@ Valera >
I'm trying to return all values from list/set B that aren't in list/set A.  As I I need the uniques that appear in the larger list for later in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets:

```
set(b) - set(a)
Out[65]: {7, 8}
```

Or more explicitly:

```
set(b).difference(a)
Out[67]: {7, 8}
```

For symmetric difference, you can use `^`. It will return elements that are in a or b, but not in both. Assume `a` has an additional element, 9:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
set(b) ^ set(a)
Out[70]: {7, 8, 9}
```

Or,

```
set(b).symmetric_difference(a)
Out[71]: {7, 8, 9}
```

If they are already sets, you can just do `b - a` or `b ^ a`.

Your attempt does not work because there is no item in `a` which is not in `b`. For that difference (`b-a`), you need: `[item for item in b if item not in a]`.

Comment: I think I tried "final = set(b) - set(a)" however from memory it returned 6,7,8 I will have another go on when I have access to the script again and will see what happens.

Just made an edit to main post just as I think I made it a tad confusing the "lists" are already in sets and were not reconverted back to lists, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)  to count the number of occurrences of each element from both lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9]

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

d = defaultdict(int)

for num in chain(a, b):
    d[num] += 1


print([key for key, value in d.items() if value == 1])
```

Output:

```
[7, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list(set(a)-set(b))+list(set(b)-set(a))
```

Comment: Too many sets were created and destroyed in the making of this one-liner